# Regex returning last character of string?

Tags: regex, perl, rainmeter

'Ello, so I'm using Rainmeter and I just want to get the last character of a string using Regex. Rainmeter uses Perl regex. The string is just two characters long, it's just minutes (so just two numbers) and I need the second digit.

This is what I have for getting just the first digit.

```
[MeasureMinutePrefix]
Measure=Time
Format=%M
RegExpSubstitute=1
Substitute="^(.{1,1}).+$":"\1"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Rainmeter, but extrapolating from your example, this should do it:

```
Substitute="^.*(.)$":"\1"
```

BTW, there's no need for `{1,1}` in the regexp. That's the normal meaning of any non-quantified pattern, it matches exactly once.

Comment: Note that `^(.).$` for the first digit and `^.(.)$` for the second would also work.  The quantifiers let you generalize to more than two-digit numbers, though; no matter how many characters there are, `^(.).*$` gets the first and `^.*(.)$` gets the last.

Answer (score -1):

```
Substitute="^.{1}(.{1,1})$":"\1"
```

or

```
Substitute="^\d(\d)$":"\1"
```

Comment: So? Is that a wrong solution? It works. I tried to keep same format that currently is there and offered another solution.

Comment: Fair enough, Andrey.  I didn't say it was wrong, nor was my comment related to your downvote.  I just think some consistency would be better.  A more exact parallel to the original code would be `^.+(.{1,1})$`, for example. If you're going to restrict it to exactly two characters, as stated in the problem but not in the code, then it would have made more sense to me to reuse the `{1,1}`, or get rid of both instances of it; introducing `{1}` to the mix just seems confusing for no benefit.